# How create RouteCollectionBuilderTest.php in vendor/symfony/routing/Tests in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I follow one project to make practice my laravel skill.
I found one thing is this project make admin route in RouteCollectionBuilderTest file that located in symfony/routing/Tests folder.
this Tests folder is not present in original laravel folder structure.
what logic make this Tests folder ,is this API testing?
[image]

by this    `$routes->add('/admin', 'AppBundle:Admin:dashboard', 'admin_dashboard');`
admin route can redirect by `http://localhost:8000/admin`
I want to know is how can make this logic .
here is all files that incude in Test folder
[image]

I want to know how to make this files and why this files need in project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing [tests for the `symfony/routing` Composer package](https://github.com/symfony/routing/tree/5.4/Tests). These are tests specific to the Routing package, unrelated to Laravel.

Usually these files can be excluded in the package export by using the `export-ignore` flag in a `.gitattributes` file ([example in symfony/routing](https://github.com/symfony/routing/blob/5.4/.gitattributes#L1)). This export with exclusion happens when you use the `--prefer-dist` option in Composer.

If you use `--prefer-source` or a similar configuration, or if you did a `git clone` directly, these test files will still be included.

You don't want to depend on those test files for your own application tests. Instead, read about [Laravel's HTTP testing options](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests) for asserting your route functionality.

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_a_basic_request()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```